# Aggregate measurements in an efficient manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

Im trying to add together measurements from a data set. I have measurements from every minut, and i need to find the sum of every hour for a whole year.

This is what i have at the moment. It works but it is slow. There might be more problems with it, but it was what made sense.

```
def aggregate_measurements(tvec, data, period):
tvec_a = []
data_a = []

        if period == 'hour':
            for i in range(0, len(tvec), 60):
        
            timecomp = tvec.iloc[i:i+60]
            datacomp = data.iloc[i:i+60]
            tvec_a.append(timecomp.iloc[0]['year':'second'])
            data_summeret = datacomp.sum()
            data_a.append(data_summeret)
        return tvec_a, data_a
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should not loop over indices in a loop but rather concatenate all data in a single DataFrame and use `groupby` or `resample` to aggregate

Comment: In your code `data` seems to be both the input data and the result. Is this your real code?

Comment: The assignment gives me the data in two data frames. 

Yes this is my code, it should take in data and modify it, and replace it with the new data

Comment: You do not replace data here after modifying anything, but directly replace it with an empty list...

Comment: I can't post the whole code in the comment, but what I posted works for what is intended, it is just slow.

I just updated the question with more of my code

Comment: You haven't even shown what the data looks like. You must provide a reproducible input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using vectorized operations whenever possible. Like groupby

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming tvec is a datetime column in your DataFrame. If not - convert
df['hour'] = df['tvec'].dt.floor('H')  # Create a new column with the hour component of the timestamp

hourly_data = df.groupby('hour')['data'].sum().reset_index()
```

The dt.floor('H') is used to round down the timestamps to the nearest hour

Comment: I have two data frames, one with the time in different columns and one with measurements. Do I need to combine them into one data frame to use your example?